# NSPersistentStore - CoreData Retention/Deletion based on disk size of NSPersistentStore

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite, core-data

Forgive me as I tend to not ask questions so I hope I'm doing this right. I have a sqlite backed CoreData stack.

Question: Is there a way to delete data from CoreData based on the size of the NSPersistentStore and to resize said store?

Background: I plan on writing lots of data to different tables. Some of these tables are in separate NSPersistentStore and in my case that means separate sqlite files.

I had written a process for checking if the sqlite file had exceeded a certain amount of megabytes so that I could delete some data from the file.

It seems that after I delete rows from the database the file stays the same size and doesn't resize. The `NSSQLite​Manual​Vacuum​Option` was set on the persistent store so I expected this file to resize eventually but it never does which causes my process to keep trying to delete my rows.

I even tried connecting to the file and forcing the VACUUM command using sql and that seemed to only work sometimes.

```
    func forceCleanUp {
                deleteDatabaseRows()
            
                //Perform Cleanup
                var db: OpaquePointer?
                guard sqlite3_open(path, &db) == SQLITE_OK else {
                    print("error opening database")
                    sqlite3_close(db)
                    db = nil
                    return
                }

                //Probably not a good idea.
                if sqlite3_exec(db, "VACUUM", nil, nil, nil) != SQLITE_OK {
                    let errmsg = String(cString: sqlite3_errmsg(db)!)
                    print("error running VACCUUM: \(errmsg)")
                } 

    }
```

Something tells me that even if this DID work consistently it wouldn't be a good idea as it messes around with underlying settings.

Comment: This is really a SQLite question, not anything about Core Data. You might get better info if you edited the question and tags to focus on SQLite.

Comment: Thanks @TomHarrington. I'll do just that.